# Four column horizonatal form, bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this horizontal form (from the docs example).

I'd like to add radiobutton before the labels, and also a dropbox to the right. So I need a four (aligned) column horizontal form. Whats the best way to do this?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: so have you tried anything apart from this basic stuff that you have done from the docs example????

Comment: Yeha been messing around a couple hours. Can't get a hang of it.

Comment: Can you show us on jsfiddle what you have tried which didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**radio and drop-down next to label**](http://jsfiddle.net/4SH8Z/1/)

change form type to `form-inline`

before any `label`, just do this :

```
   <input type="radio" class="" placeholder="" name="radio_btn" />

   <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label inline-show ">Email</label>

   <select>
     <option>1</option>    
     <option>1</option>    
     <option>1</option>
   </select>
```